# C++: pointers and compiler (aliasing?) optimization

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization

I've ran into a trouble with compiler optimization so I need some help.
I've got the following code:

```
typedef struct {
   int32_t  DataLen;
   char     Data[1];
} MTEMSG; 
MTEMSG *IfaceData;
int Interface = MTEStructure2(ConnectionHandle, &IfaceData); 
int32_t * pointer = (int32_t *)IfaceData->Data;
ReadFromBuf(pointer);
```

MTEStructure2 is a third-party function, that allocates a block of memory starting with `IfaceData->Data` and having `IfaceData->DataLen` length. This buffer consists of multiple 1-byte character lines, each line is preceded by that line's length (a 4-byte integer). So I've got a function to read one line:

```
int * MTEGetString(int * pointer, std::string & result) 
{
    int datalen = 0;
    datalen = *pointer;
    char * data;
    data = (char *) (pointer + 1);
    result = std::string(data, datalen);
    pointer = (int *)(data + datalen);
    return pointer;
}
```

It is called from `ReadFromBuf` like this:

```
int* ReadFromBuf(int * pointer)
{
    std::string name="", caption="", description="";
    pointer = MTEGetString(pointer, name);
    pointer = MTEGetString(pointer, caption);
    pointer = MTEGetString(pointer, description);
    // etc
}
```

And everything works fine in debug mode (I'm using Qt 5.0.1 with gcc 4.7.2 under WinXP). But as long as I switch to release mode, the program crashes on `result = std::string(data, datalen);`, because `datalen` (and by that moment the whole buffer, I guess) is not valid. Everything works fine again after I disable optimization for release builds (`QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O2`).

I've done some reading, and the closest thing I've found is an aliasing optimization. But compiler gives no warning even with `-Wall` option, and `-fno-strict-aliasing` doesn't help, so I'm totally in the dark. Of course, I could build the project with disabled optimization, but I would really like to understand what's going on.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just use the `address-of operator` on `IfaceData->Data`?

Comment: How do you find the end of the data? It looks like the code just keeps going... and going... and going... (I would personally suspect Undefined Behaviour unless there's clear evidence of anything else.)

Comment: `IfaceData` is a type. How can you do `&IfaceData` and `IfaceData->Data`? Can you post the _actual_ code? Also, you are looking at the pointer as `int32_t *`, but then passing it as `int *`?

Comment: Furthermore, how can the third party allocate _a block of memory starting with IfaceData->Data_? It's an array, not a pointer. Do you mean it allocates something like `malloc(sizeof(IfaceData) + some_extra_bytes)` and then overwrites a given `IfaceData *` with the result?

Comment: @Shahbaz Sorry this was a typo, first line must be read as `typedef struct {int32_t  DataLen; char Data[1];} MTEMSG; MTEMSG *IfaceData;` As for allocating memory - it probably works the way you described, I'm not really sure

Comment: @Casey I still have to cast this pointer to `int*`, so I don't see how that could make a difference

Comment: @molbdnilo I understand your concerns but neither `ReadFromBuf` is recursive nor I reach the end of the buffer.

Comment: @Shahbaz `int32_t` and `int` are the same 4 bytes for me, so that doesn't make any difference, does it?

Comment: @mr.fIErcE How do you know you're not reaching the end of the buffer? You're not showing any error checking, and not verifying that you don't read beyond `DataLen` bytes. (And the undefined behaviour I worry about can be somewhere else entirely.)

Comment: @molbdnilo the buffer has a strict structure - it always consists of four blocks, which are header and three object descriptions. I am reading only three of them, and the problem occurs while reading the very first line in the header block. But I totally agree it would be right to check for buffer edges, I hope i will implement it someday :)

Comment: @mr.fIErcE, on _your_ machine. The whole purpose of `int32_t` was to make code portable across many machines.

Comment: @Shahbaz I thought `int32_t` was some kind of typedef, but now I see I was wrong. Still changing `int32_t *` to `int *` didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @mr.fIErcE, `int32_t` is a typedef. On some machines it's typedefed to `int`. On others could be different. That wasn't your problem though, I was merely mentioning it.

Comment: Regarding your problem, it seems to me that C++ is not being tolerant of the "struct hack" used by your library.

Comment: @Shahbaz I'm still confused with the fact that my code stops working after I turn code optimization on. I believe the buffer referenced by `pointer` is valid until I pass it to subfunction, I'll try to clarify that one tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I've found that I had both `-std=gnu++11` and `-std=c++1x` in gcc call for release build. After I removed `-std=gnu++11` everything worked like a charm.